# Random number without repeat in swiftUI

Tags: swift, swiftui

I have an array of numbers that I would like to generate randomly without repeating since I have noticed that there are a few numbers that get repeated back to back. this is my code

```
struct t: View {
    var body: some View {
        ranNum()
    }
}

struct t_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        t()
    }
}


struct ranNum: View {
    
    static let ranNum = [1,2,3,4,5,6]
    
    @State var randomNum = Self.ranNum.randomElement()!
    
    var body: some View {
        
        
            
            VStack{
                
                Text("\(randomNum)")
                    .padding()
                    .multilineTextAlignment(.center)
                    .background(Color.white.opacity(0.5))
                    .cornerRadius(10)
                    .frame(width: 390, alignment: /*@START_MENU_TOKEN@*/.center/*@END_MENU_TOKEN@*/)
                
                
                
                Button(action: {
                    randomNum = Self.ranNum.randomElement()!
                }) {
                    Image(systemName: "arrow.counterclockwise.circle.fill")
                        .foregroundColor(.black)
                        .font(.system(size: 30))
                        .padding()
                }
            }
            
        }
    }
```

is this problem solvable in swiftUI???

Comment: If you try to simulate a die roll you could use `GameplayKit`'s random algorithms which [already include scenarios like this](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/gameplaykit/gkrandomdistribution/1495634-d6)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This approach uses an extra observable class. It copies the 6 numbers into a temporary array. On tap one random number is removed from the array (this number is being displayed) so each number is only used once. If the array is empty the cycle starts over.

```
class Random : ObservableObject {
    var array = [Int]()
    
    @Published var randomNumber = 0
    
    func next() {
        if array.isEmpty { array = [1,2,3,4,5,6] }
        let index = Int.random(in: 0..<array.count)
        randomNumber = array.remove(at: index)
    }
}

struct RanNum: View {
    
    @StateObject private var random = Random()
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack{
            
            Text(random.randomNumber == 0 ? "" : "\(random.randomNumber)")
                .padding()
                .multilineTextAlignment(.center)
                .background(Color.white.opacity(0.5))
                .cornerRadius(10)
                .frame(width: 390, alignment: .center)
            
            Button(action: {
                random.next()
            }) {
                Image(systemName: "arrow.counterclockwise.circle.fill")
                    .foregroundColor(.black)
                    .font(.system(size: 30))
                    .padding()
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: is it possible to start the view with a number already showing instead of clicking the button to start the sequince?

Comment: Yes, add the `.onAppear` modifier and call `random.next()`. Then you can delete `random.randomNumber == 0 ? "" :`

Comment: I would also like to use the same process for an array of strings, I tried altering the code but I am having trouble. would this process also work with strings instead of ints?

Comment: Of course it works also with strings.

Answer (score 0):

You could first randomize your array, then pop last element each time you want a number

```
static var ranNum = [1,2,3,4,5,6].shuffle()

@State var randomNum = Self.ranNum.popLast()
```

Comment: You're correct, changed to `var`. And yes, it returns `nil` if empty, same as `randomElement` OP used, except I got rid of force unwrap